# Erro ao iniciar app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quando tento executar um aplicativo pelo Android Studio no emulador Genymotion acontece um erro inesperado e o app não abre.

[image: Erro do aplicativo]

E o *log* da aba *Logcat* do Android Studio retorna o seguinte:

```
03-14 19:06:21.367 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
03-14 19:06:21.367 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
03-14 19:06:21.367 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
03-14 19:06:21.367 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
03-14 19:06:21.367 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
03-14 19:06:21.367 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>
03-14 19:06:21.371 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onDraw
03-14 19:06:21.371 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
03-14 19:06:21.371 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
03-14 19:06:21.383 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
03-14 19:06:21.383 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados, PID: 3725
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados/br.com.meuprojeto.dm.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at br.com.meuprojeto.dm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700bd
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:209)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at br.com.meuprojeto.dm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Obs: Quando iniciei o projeto ele rodava em todas as versões do Android, e agora apenas na versão 8.0.

Comment: Esse parece o log da aba `Run`. Edite a pergunta e inclua o erro (normalmente em vermelho) na aba `LogCat`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, é o log da pasta run! Porém ele aparece todo em uma unica cor. Nada em vermelho.

Comment: Em `Run` serão logados os eventos relacionados à instalação do aplicativo. No `LogCat` são logados os dados relacionados à execução do mesmo. É lá que as exceptions (erros) serão informados.

Comment: Quando verifiquei o LogCat ele retorna o seguinte erro:

03-14 19:06:21.367 3725-3725/br.com.meuprojeto.deliverymercados E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Esse é só o primeiro, aparece muitos.
De anti mão já agradeço sua disponibilidade de ajudar!

Comment: Por favor [edite seu post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/368566/edit) substituindo os códigos de erro anteriores pelos novos. Certifique-se de colocar o código entre as aspas triplas (``` ... ```) que formatam o código corretamente.

Comment: Feito. Desculpe pelos erros de formatação, sou novo aqui. Mais uma vez muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja as exceptions descritas no erro:

> Unable to start activity [...**MainActivity**]: android.view.**InflateException**: Binary **XML file line #12**: Error inflating **class ImageView**.

Indica que não foi possível iniciar a `MainActivity` devido a um erro ao inflar (criar) uma `ImageView`; e o erro está na linha 12 do XML de layout.

Descendo mais um pouco o stack trace (erro):

> Caused by: android.content.res.**Resources$NotFoundException**: Resource ID #0x7f0700bd

Indica que o recurso (drawable no seu caso) não foi encontrado.

---

Para resolver o problema, verifique a linha 12 do layout utilizado na `MainActivity`, então certifique-se que ele está acessível. Algumas causas possíveis são:

- O drawable foi excluído por completo;
- O drawable existe mas apenas para configurações específicas: veja [esta documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) sobre recursos alternativos.

Ao substituir a fonte da imagem (provavelmente `android:src`) - ou corrigir a pasta no caso de recursos alternativos -, o problema deve ser resolvido.